# Simple loop with non integer index

Tags: python, numpy, loops, numpy-slicing

I am trying to write down the following code:

giving an array B, `len(B) = n-1`; and knowing `A[0]=1` :

`A[n]-A[0] = sum(for  i=0 to n-1) B[n-i- 1/2]*(A[i+1]-A[i])`.

The code I wrote is the following:

```py
nn = len(B)
A = np.zeros_like(B)
for n in range(nn):
    summ = 0
    for i in range(0, nn-1):
        delta = (n - 1/2)
        xx = B[delta-i]
        print(xx)
        summ = summ + xx*(A[i+1]-A[i])
    A[0] = 1
    A[1:n] = summ
```

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Like the error says, non-integer numerical values are not valid indices.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be in line

```
delta = (n - 1/2)
xx = B[delta-i]
```

because delta may not be int and only ints may be in index. May it halp:

```
delta = (n - 1/2)
xx = B[int(delta)-i]
```